# Find $a^{100}+b^{100}+ab$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

$a$ and $b$ are the roots of the equation $x^2+x+1=0$.

Then what is the value of $a^{100}+b^{100}+ab$?
Here's what I found out:
$$a+b=-1$$
$$ab=1$$
but how to use this to find that I don't know! Someone please answer my query.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718822/roots-of-a-quadratic-equation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be a root of $x^2+x+1=0$, then $\omega^3=1$. Thus
$$
a^{100}+b^{100}+ab=a+b+ab.
$$

Comment: is this w the cube root of unity?

Comment: Yes, because $\omega^3-1=(\omega-1)(\omega^2+\omega+1)=(\omega-1)\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: It's **a** cube root of unity.  $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$ means $(\omega-1)(\omega^2 + \omega + 1) = 0$.  Distribute on the left to get $\omega^3 - 1$.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of your equation are $$x = -\frac{1}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

We have $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}$, both which remain unchanged in magnitude and direction upon exponentiating 100 times as $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} = e^{\frac{200 \pi i}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}} = e^{\frac{400 \pi i}{3}}$, telling us that $a^{100} = a$ and $b^{100} = b$ and thus $a + b + ab = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not require flashes of inspiration.

$a^2+a+1=0$ implies $a^2=-a-1$ and so $a^3=-a(a+1)=-(a^2+a)=-(-a-1+a)=1$. Therefore, $a^{100}=a^{99}a=(a^3)^{33}a=a$.

The same holds for $b$ and so
$$
a^{100}+b^{100}+ab=a+b+ab=-1+1=0
$$